# What impact does rent exemption have on validators' economics?

Tags: validator, rent

I understand that rent is only collected on legacy accounts that were created in the past,  before it was enforced that all accounts be rent-exempt by depositing 2 years of rent.

While the rent went to the validators as theirs to keep, the rent-exempt deposit is just that, a deposit.

Does that mean the validators earn less now?

Has rent income been replaced with something else? If so, what?

Answer (score 2):

Requiring rent exemption on accounts does remove the SOL payout during rent collection. Rent is now more like a deposit to allocate space.

There is not any specific feature meant to replace what was claimed during rent collection.